# Adjoint and closure of the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, operator-algebras, fourier-transform

Let $T= -\Delta$   and   $D=\{u\in L^2 , \Delta u \in L^2\}$ 
i want to show that $(T,D)$ is a self-adjoint operator.

The first idea i got  is to proof that it is closed and $Ker(T^*\pm i) =\{0\}$ unfortunatly i have been blocked against his closedness , such that i can't calculate that kernel because i haven't the domain of the adjoint.

so the second way was  more simple which is to show that $R(T\pm i ) = H$( whole space )
i can proceed but Lax-Milgram theorem and it is ok.

The third one which is the most interresting was to make the Fourier transform of the operator and it will be $Tu=Fu$ such that $F$ is a real measurable function and $D=\{u \in L^2 , Fu \in L^2\}$ but i still confused about the equivalence between the self-adjonction of this two operators.

My other quastion is what if $D= \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0$.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\partial=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain $\mathcal{D}(\partial)$ consisting of all locally absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f'\in L^2$. You can show that $f\in\mathcal{D}(\partial)$ iff
$$
                  f\in L^2, \xi\hat{f}(\xi) \in L^2.
$$
Furthermore, $\partial f = (\xi\hat{f})^{\vee}$. So $\partial$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on $L^2$. That's enough to show that $\partial$ is selfadjoint on $\mathcal{D}(\partial)$. The Fourier transform is a unitary "diagonalization" of $\partial$. The operator $\partial$ is essentially selfadjoint on $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$.

Your operator $T = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is selfadjoint on $\mathcal{D}(\partial^2)$, and $T=\partial^2$. The restriction of $T$ to $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}$ is essentially selfadjoint.

Comment: Hello sir ,thank you a lot, i found your answer really usefull, but i still thinking about the clousedness, any hint please ? how do you think about the others way i cited in the question ? :)

Comment: @D.abdelhakim : What is the precise domain you are using for your operator $T$? How are you defining differentiability for an $L^2$ function that is defined as an equivalence class of functions that are equal a.e.? And, are you using differentiability or something stronger, such as absolute continuity that I am using. I suspect you are running into problems because you have not found a precise definition of the operator on functions in $L^2$.

Comment: I want to do that in the general case for any open subset $\Omega $ from $\mathcal {R}^n $ and for the derivation ,For the first case i am using the weak topology (by distributions ) the second one i use the strong one.